# plotting from a data frame in pandas

Tags: python

Please I'm new to pandas and want to obtain a multiple time series plot with the dataframe below using TIMESTAMP as index.

```
TIMESTAMP            shf_1      shf_2       shf_3
2016-06-18 09:20:00  24.98201   40.98293    18.75554
2016-06-18 09:25:00  24.59746   37.85617    18.11409
2016-06-18 09:30:00  24.93322   40.07658    20.18585
2016-06-18 09:35:00  25.79265   40.91981    21.60389
2016-06-18 09:40:00  26.49355   45.02221    23.86291
2016-06-18 09:45:00  25.65839   42.93957    23.56091
2016-06-18 09:50:00  28.22184   47.68266    25.76584
2016-06-18 09:55:00  28.68465   49.86813    26.68878
2016-06-18 10:00:00  25.28899   48.88993    26.958
2016-06-18 10:05:00  22.24257   43.74584    24.88566
2016-06-18 10:10:00  21.02077   39.90298    23.48933
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using the latest version of pandas and want to glance quickly at that data, use:

```
import matplotlib.plyplot as plt

df["shf_1"].plot()  
df["shf_2"].plot() 
df["shf_3"].plot() 
plt.show()
```